# Para que serve o construtor de cópia do C++? Como devo implementá-lo?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, objetos, método, construtor

Sou programador `Java` e atualmente estou estudando `C++`. Além dos construtores "normais" (o construtor padrão e o parametrizado) o `C++` conta com um construtor de cópia. Gostaria de saber para que serve e como devo implementá-lo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O conceito pode parecer estranho para um programador Java, porque nessa linguagem os objetos sempre são tratados com "semântica de referência". Quando se faz algo como:

```
Objeto obj1 = new Objeto();
Objeto obj2 = obj1;
obj2.alteraValor(4); //Alteração é refletida em obj1
```

ambas as variáveis passam a referenciar o mesmo objeto, e portanto alterações feitas a partir de qualquer uma delas são refletidas em ambas.

Já em C++, o normal é a chamada "semântica de valor", e o comportamento dessa expressão é diferente:

```
Objeto obj1;
Objeto obj2 = obj1;
obj2.alteraValor(4); //Alteração só é feita em obj2, obj1 fica como estava
```

quando um objeto é criado a partir da atribuição de outro, ele copia os atributos do original, e cada um segue seu caminho após isso. E esta cópia é feita com a invocação do construtor de cópia.

---

Na grande maioria das vezes você não precisa se preocupar com isso, o compilador gera um construtor de cópia para a sua classe, que faz a cópia de todos os atributos dela um a um. Você precisa se preocupar com isso quando sua classe faz manipulação de recursos, para evitar que tenha dois objetos apontando para o mesmo recurso inadvertidamente.

```
class Objeto {
    int *recurso;
public:
    Objeto() { //Construtor principal - aloca recurso
        recurso = new int;
    }
    Objeto(const Objeto &outro) { //Construtor de cópia - copia recurso
        recurso = new int;
        *recurso = *(outro.recurso);
    }
    ~Objeto() { //destrutor - libera recurso
        delete recurso;
    }                
};
```

Neste exemplo, sem implementar o construtor de cópia, uma operação de atribuição como a do primeiro exemplo faria com que ambos os objetos apontassem para o mesmo recurso, e assim quando seus destrutores forem invocados ele seria deletado duas vezes, o que pode gerar vários erros em tempo de execução, como corrupção de *heap*.

Esta classe ainda deveria ter sobrecarregado o operador de atribuição, pois se em algum outro momento for feito `obj1 = obj3`, teremos o mesmo problema de 2 objetos apontando para o mesmo recurso. Este operador pode ser implementado assim:

```
class Objeto {
    ...

    Objeto &operator=(const Objeto &outro) {
        *recurso = *(outro.recurso);
        return *this;
    }

    ...
};
```

Assim chegamos no conceito conhecido como Regra dos Três do C++:

> Se sua classe possuir um desses três: destrutor, construtor de cópia
>   ou operador de atribuição, provavelmente ela precisa de todos os três.

---

Em C++ 11, além de criar objetos a partir de cópias, também é possível "roubar" o estado de outros objetos, principalmente temporários ou que estejam para ser destruídos. Para essa operação funcionar a classe precisa prover um construtor de movimentação (tradução horrível para *move constructor*) e o operador de atribuição de movimentação (*move assignment operator*).

Acho que foge ao escopo desta resposta explicar o conceito por trás deles, mas eles adicionariam mais dois elementos à regra dos três mencionada antes, transformando-a na Regra dos Cinco. Mas implementar todos esses métodos para gerenciar recursos quase nunca é necessário, pois a linguagem agora fornece classes como `shared_ptr` e `unique_ptr` que cuidam disso automaticamente. Usá-las para o gerenciamento de recursos deixa a semântica do que se quer fazer explícita, previne algumas dores de cabeça, e elimina a necessidade de escrever os destrutores, construtores e operadores de atribuição especiais. Este é o princípio da Regra do Zero.

Comment: nota: Uma referência completa à regra dos 3 no dias atuais, faria referência [à regra dos 5 e à regra do 0](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).

Comment: Concordo com o @pepper_chico, falar da antiga regra dos 3 e não dizer que atualmente o preferido é a regra do 0, e em alguns casos a regra do 5, é uma das poucas coisas que me fazem não dar upvote.

Comment: Eu comecei a colocar uma explicação das regras do 5 e do 0, mas aí já estava falando de move construtors e move semantics e a resposta estava ficando com o triplo do tamanho necessário. Tentei dar uma versão resumida.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas e pelos comentários. Estou pesquisando mais sobre o assunto e com certeza tudo o que foi discutido vai me acrescentar muito.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente falando, um construtor de cópia serve para fazer uma cópia, ou seja, para que você construa um objeto que é cópia de outro. 
Os construtores de cópia tem as seguintes assinaturas:

`MyClass( const MyClass& other );
 MyClass( MyClass& other );
 MyClass( volatile const MyClass& other );
 MyClass( volatile MyClass& other );`

[obtido de www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/)

Caso você não forneça um construtor de cópia o compilador irá gerar um de maneira implícita, mas quando você precisa de algum tratamento especial ao fazer a cópia é necessário escrever o construtor de maneira explícita, como quando não se deseja simplesmente copiar um ponteiro, mas se alocar uma nova área de memória e copiar seu conteúdo, por exemplo.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de construtor de cópia:

```
class MinhaClasse
{
public:
MinhaClasse()
{
    ...
    // construtor de MinhaClasse
    ...
}

// Construtor de cópia
MinhaClasse(const MinhaClasse& outra) :
    inteiro(outra.inteiro)
{
}
private:
int inteiro;
};
```