# O que é sobrecarga de operadores?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem, sobrecarga

Em algumas linguagens de programação como `C++` é possível fazer sobrecarga de operadores. O que é e para que serve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sobre-carga de operadores nada mais é do que alterar o comportamento de um operador da linguagem, como `+`, `-`, etc.

A função dele é mais cosmética, voltada para a simplificação da leitura e entendimento do código. Mas permite simplificar o gerenciamento de memória em alguns casos (em especial de classes imutáveis de tamanho arbitrátio, como strings).

Internamente, ele é implementado como um método tradicional, e portanto permite todas as otimizações e cabíveis de um método (além de poder ser simplesmente substituído por um).

**Aplicações**

*Observação: mostrarei o mínimo possível de código, focando na teoria.*

Como dito, a aplicação da sobre-carga de operadores é basicamente cosmética.

Exemplo: imagine que você esteja implementando sua classe `MyString` e deseja adicionar a funcionalidade de concatenação. Você poderia então implementar um método `MyString::concat`, e então utiliza-lo:

```
s3 = s1.concat(s2);
```

Graças a sobre-carga de operadores, você pode implementar um comportamento exclusivo para a classe `MyString` para o operador de soma `+`, que realiza a concatenação. Deste modo, o código acima poderia ser reescrito como:

```
s3 = s1 + s2;
```

Outro uso, é a realização do `type casting` implícito. Isso ocorre muito em C++ onde você pode fazer o tipo `std::string` receber um `char*`:

```
std::string s = "array de char";
```

Para que isto funcione, a classe `std::string` sobre-carrega o operador de atribuição `=` para receber um `char*` e retornar um `std::string`.

Neste caso em específico, a sobre-carga é declarada como:

```
string& operator= (const char* s);
```

Outro fator interessante, é que você pode ter vários comportamentos para o operador, dependendo dos operandos associados. Na própria classe `std::string`, o operador de atribuição possui 3 sobre-cargas, cada uma para um tipo específico de dado:

```
string& operator= (const string& str); // [1]
string& operator= (const char* s);  // [2]
string& operator= (char c); // [3]
```

Assim, as seguintes atribuições são válidas:

```
std::string s1 = "string"; // sobre-carga 2.
std::string s2 = 'a'; // sobre-carga 3.
std::string s3 = s1; // sobre-carga 1.
```

A conversão implícita de tipos é uma das maiores vantagens da sobre-carga de operadores. Do contrário, teriam que ser declarados métodos como os à seguir:

```
static string& fromStdString(const string& str); // ***
static string& fromCharArray(const char* s);
static string& fromChar(char c);
```

A primeira das sobre-cargas é grátis! O compilador cria ela automaticamente. Mas nada impede de ela ser escrita manualmente. Isto, de fato, é o que ocorre na `std::string`, pois ela é uma classe imutável e possui contadores de referências para realizar o controle de memória.

Equivalentemente sendo utilizados como:

```
std::string s1 = std::string::fromCharArray("string"); // sobre-carga 2.
std::string s2 = std::string::fromChar('a'); // sobre-carga 3.
std::string s3 = s1; // sobre-carga 1.
```

**Conclusão**

Sobre-carga de operadores apesar do nome complicado não é tecnologia extra-terrestre. Ela facilita várias coisas (em especial gerenciamento de memória), mas em nenhum dos casos ela é mandatória, embora possa ser facilitadora.

Comment: Achei sua resposta muito boa, porém adicionei mais uma dúvida para quem começar a usar esta facilidade(como eu), não cair em armadilhas e/ou cometer erros comuns.

Comment: Pra quem está aprendendo C++ e chegou até aqui, uma leitura complementar muito importante é sobre [Construtores de Cópia](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10806/para-que-serve-o-construtor-de-c%C3%B3pia-do-c-como-devo-implement%C3%A1-lo).

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado pela resposta. :)

Answer (score 2):

Os operadores normais estao sobrecarredos em C tambem.

Por exemplo, o operador `+` serve para adicionar inteiros (`42 + 12`), para adicionar numeros de virgula flutuante (`0.5 + 3.14159`), para "avancar" um ponteiro (`string + 5`), ...

Mas nao 'e possivel usar o `+` entre, por exemplo, um ponteiro e um `double`

```
string + 3.14169 // erro
```

Algumas linguagens de programacao permitem definir a operacao a efectuar quando se usa um operador com operandos que nao estejam previamente definidos.

Assim podes, por exemplo, definir que somar um inteiro a uma lista acrescenta essa inteiro no fim da lista (em C terias que usar uma funcao para isso).

```
// exemplo teorico: nao sei C++ nem outra linguagem com esta potencialidade
Lista seq = 42;
// print seq devolve 42
seq = seq + 3;
// print seq devolve 42, 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Sobrecarga de operador significa redefinir a operação que o simbolo irá realizar como o operador `+` de Java que para numeros inteiros realização uma soma e para strings uma concatenação o operador `=` em PHP que pode ter sua função modificada com métodos mágicos.