# Passar objeto de classe como parâmetro de construtor em C++

Tags: c++, classes, construtor

Boa tarde pessoal!
Estou estudando para uma prova de C++ que farei essa semana, e estou tendo dificuldade ao passar um objeto como parâmetro de construtor. Poderiam me explicar o jeito correto de fazer?

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Data {
public:
    Data(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
        this->dia = dia;
        this->mes = mes;
        this->ano = ano;
    };
    void setData(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
        this->dia = dia;
        this->mes = mes;
        this->ano = ano;
    };

    string getData() {
        string d = to_string(this->dia);
        string m = to_string(this->mes);
        string a = to_string(this->ano);
        return d + "/" + m + "/" + a;
    }

private:
    int dia, mes, ano;
};


class Pessoa {
public:
    Pessoa(Data d) {
        this->data = d;
    };
private:
    Data data;
};


int main()
{
    Data data1(1, 2, 1995);
    Data *data2 = new Data(3,4,1996);

    cout << data1.getData() << endl;
    cout << data2->getData() << endl;

    //Pessoa p(data1);
    //Pessoa *p2 = new Pessoa(data2);
    return 0;
}
```

Como possível ver no trecho abaixo, tentei criar um construtor que recebesse uma Data e alocasse a mesma no campo encapsulado Data:

```
class Pessoa {
public:
    Pessoa(Data d) {
        this->data = d;
    };
private:
    Data data;
};
```

Porém ao compilar, tenho esse problema:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Aprendizado1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\Lucas\DESENVOLVIMENTO\12 Semestre\Aprendizado1\main.cpp||In constructor 'Pessoa::Pessoa(Data)':|
D:\Lucas\DESENVOLVIMENTO\12 Semestre\Aprendizado1\main.cpp|33|error: no matching function for call to 'Data::Data()'|
D:\Lucas\DESENVOLVIMENTO\12 Semestre\Aprendizado1\main.cpp|8|note: candidate: Data::Data(int, int, int)|
D:\Lucas\DESENVOLVIMENTO\12 Semestre\Aprendizado1\main.cpp|8|note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided|
D:\Lucas\DESENVOLVIMENTO\12 Semestre\Aprendizado1\main.cpp|6|note: candidate: constexpr Data::Data(const Data&)|
D:\Lucas\DESENVOLVIMENTO\12 Semestre\Aprendizado1\main.cpp|6|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
D:\Lucas\DESENVOLVIMENTO\12 Semestre\Aprendizado1\main.cpp|6|note: candidate: constexpr Data::Data(Data&&)|
D:\Lucas\DESENVOLVIMENTO\12 Semestre\Aprendizado1\main.cpp|6|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Se eu adiciono um construtor vazio (sem parâmetros), funciona, porém nao acho que seja a solução correta. Como seria o correto? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Esta faltando o construtor de cópia na classe `Data`,

Nessa linha você chama um construtor de cópia mais não existe:

```
this->data = d;
```

Por isso que o compilador mostra esses erros

Aqui explica o que é um construtor de cópia e como implementa-lo [Para que serve o construtor de cópia do C++? Como devo implementá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10806/para-que-serve-o-construtor-de-c%C3%B3pia-do-c-como-devo-implement%C3%A1-lo)

Você poderia passar uma referencia do objeto,
Usando referencias sua classe `Pessoa` ficaria simplesmente assim:

```
class Pessoa {
public:
    Pessoa(const Data& d) {
        this->data = d;
    };
private:
    const Data& data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

O construtor da classe Pessoa está "errado". Da forma que ele está escrito, ele tenta chamar o construtor padrão da classe Data e, apenas após, tenta copiar o parâmetro d para o membro data. Como não existe um construtor padrão para a classe Data, a compilação falha.

Para corrigir isso, deve ser utilizado *constructor members initializer list* https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
class Pessoa {
public:
    Pessoa(Data d) 
    : data(d) {};
private:
    Data data;
};
```